# ANDROID How do I pass variable between two classes

Tags: android, class

I have two classes: `SingleTouchEventView` and `Output`.

How I can pass the variable `eventX` from `SingleTouchEventView` to `Output` and display it in a textview?

```
public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();
    private final String TAG = "LOG";

    public static Handler handler; 
    private long delay;
    protected boolean hideView = false;

    public void setDelay(long delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    Handler h2 = new Handler() {
    };
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            onTouchUp();
        }
    };
    public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);     
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                h2.removeCallbacks(run);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                h2.postDelayed(run, delay);
                if(hideView) {
                    return false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    protected void onTouchUp() {

    }    
    public void clear() {

    }

}
```

Derived class

```
public class Output extends SingleTouchEventView
```

Comment: Maybe creating one `static` variable and then assigning `eventX` value to it. You can access static variables by `Classname.Variablename`

Comment: The derived class has access to the member variables of base class. So simply declare a variable in `SingleTouchEventView` and use it in `Output`

Comment: as your class is view you can define getter method like `getEventX()` and use that for getting each value that you want

Comment: You have to Create Getter and Setter for Your Variable which you need to Send From one Class to another and then Using this Method You are able to Access the Variables.

Comment: Please remove code that isn't directly relevant to your question as it obfuscates what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding your core structure deeply, there is one suggestion I can make. Attempt to use an Event bus to transmit data. There are many available, I am fond of [GreenRobots EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

You simply post a class containing your required data and any class that is registered can listen for this data.